# Node.js - Extracting values from formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, busboy

I have to create an upload function where admins can upload a report for a certain user.

I have access to this data

- User ID (Number)
- Report Type (Number)
- Report (File)

When an an admin uploads a report, I want to create a directory if it doesn't exist yet like this

```
var location = __dirname + '/../../public/' + USERID + 'reports/' + filename;
```

I've been following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@asabya/file-upload-with-progress-bar-user-angular-5-and-nodejs-730852384145) to upload a file and so this is the code I have

```
function uploadReport(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    var location = __dirname + '/../../public/reports/' + filename;
    if (req.busboy) {
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            fstream = fs.createWriteStream(location);
            file.pipe(fstream);
            fstream.on('close', function () {
                console.log('file ' + filename + ' uploaded');
            });
        });
        req.busboy.on('finish', function () {
            res.json({
                success: true
            });
        });
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
    }
}
```

this is what I sent from my front end

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvS6HEnoxsgpmx646
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="participant"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryvS6HEnoxsgpmx646
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryvS6HEnoxsgpmx646
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryvS6HEnoxsgpmx646--
```

How can I extract `participant` and `type` from my form data and put them into useable variables?

Comment: Hmm, seems rather complex to upload a file and one value. This should be in the docs for busboy, so have a look there. But if I have to guess: have you checked the value of `fieldname` ?

Comment: You can extract using `req.body.participant`

Comment: This code is a bit suspicious... you're allowing the users to write to wherever on disk, basically.